# Elasticsearch bulk update with same script for multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a bulk update statement for multiple documents. I would however like to execute the same `script` for them all.

Let's take a look at the following example:

```
POST _bulk
{ "update": {"_id": "1", "_index": "test", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "script": { "source": "ctx._source.count2 = params.count2", "lang": "painless", "params": { "count2": 4 }}}
{ "update": {"_id": "2", "_index": "test", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "script": { "source": "ctx._source.count2 = params.count2", "lang": "painless", "params": { "count2": 4 }}}
{ "update": {"_id": "3", "_index": "test", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "script": { "source": "ctx._source.count2 = params.count2", "lang": "painless", "params": { "count2": 4 }}}
```

In my specific scenario, the script is more complicated.
Is there any way I can reuse the same script statement?

I deliberately do not want to use the `update_by_query` command, because of it's lack of a conflict retry mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely store your script in ES and just reference it in your bulk update:

First, store your script:

```
POST _scripts/my-script
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.count2 = params.count2"
  }
}
```

Then, use it:

```
POST _bulk
{ "update": {"_id": "1", "_index": "test", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "script": { "id": "my-script", "params": { "count2": 4 }}}
{ "update": {"_id": "2", "_index": "test", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "script": { "id": "my-script", "params": { "count2": 4 }}}
{ "update": {"_id": "3", "_index": "test", "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "script": { "id": "my-script", "params": { "count2": 4 }}}
```

Comment: Is there another way besides storing my code in the cluster?

Comment: Until 5.x, it was possible to store scripts on the file system, but this has been deprecated and removed in 6.0. What makes it difficult for you to store scripts in the cluster state?

Comment: Just bad experience with managing code in a database, but it is a good option. Thank you!